# While praying to Lord Narayana, is it necessary to pray aloud, or can we pray silently through our thoughts?

Tags: vishnu, prayer

I'm referring to simple prayers, for eg. 'I should do well in exams' or 'Please save me from difficulty'.

Comment: _"referring to simple prayers, eg.'Please save me from difficulty'."_ Asking for something from you Lord is like personal conversation between you and your beloved lord. And personal conversation is not meant to tell anyone (unless you want to). You can have you conversation with Lord silently so no one can hear it, Since some conversations are like secretes which you only want to tell to your Lord.

Comment: Related [Is it true? chanting mantra without moving lips and tongue gives more effect?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22632/3500) and [Why “Manasik Japa” is considered the best form of Japa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15321/3500)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it true? chanting mantra without moving lips and tongue gives more effect?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22632/is-it-true-chanting-mantra-without-moving-lips-and-tongue-gives-more-effect) and [Why “Manasik Japa” is considered the best form of Japa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15321/why-manasik-japa-is-considered-the-best-form-of-japa)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like praying loud makes God hear your voice. Even if you pray in your mind, its enough as long as you are doing that with respect and dedication.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE! As of now it looks like opinion based, can you please cite some sources?